# MongoDb index already exists

Tags: mongodb, indexing

When I use ensureIndex, I got a message,

> "all indexes already exist".

But there is nothing, in `getIndexes()`. Why? Can somebody help me?

```
mongos> db.UserBase.ensureIndex({"userId":1}, {"unique":true})
{
    "raw" : {
        "shard2/192.168.2.69:27024,192.168.254.107:27024,192.168.254.108:27024" : {
            "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
            "numIndexesBefore" : 2,
            "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
            "note" : "all indexes already exist",
            "ok" : 1,
            "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(1468049378, 96),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000014")
            }
        }
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
mongos> db.UserBase.getIndexes()
[ ]
```

Comment: Also can you get the client version? `mongo --version`

Comment: Try to use `db.collection.createIndex()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/#considerations) answers your question?

> **Considerations**
>
> Changed in version 3.0.0.
>
> For MongoDB 3.0 deployments using the [WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/wiredtiger/#storage-wiredtiger) storage engine,
>   if you run `db.collection.getIndexes()` from a version of the
>   [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell before 3.0 or a version of the driver prior to [3.0
>   compatible version](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/#compatibility-driver-versions), `db.collection.getIndexes()` will return no
>   data, even if there are existing indexes. For more information, see
>   [WiredTiger and Driver Version Compatibility](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/#compatibility-drivers-wired-tiger).

Try to use [db.collection.createIndex()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db.collection.createIndex).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using MongoDB higher than version 3.0.0, you might want to consider using `db.UserBase.createIndex({"userId":1}, {"unique":true})` instead. `ensureIndex()` is deprecated.

Source:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/